Majorization as sum of arbitrary subset of components of a vector
Let $x_1^\downarrow\geq \cdots\geq x_n^\downarrow$ denote the decreasingly ordered components of $x=[x_1 \cdots x_n]$.
It is commonly remarked in some books that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^k x_j^\downarrow =\displaystyle\max_{1\leq i_1<\cdots <i_k\leq n} \sum_{t=1}^kx_{i_t}$.
I only see one inequality $\leq$.
Similarly, if $x_1^\uparrow\leq \cdots \leq x_n^\uparrow$, then
$\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^k x_j^\uparrow =\displaystyle\min_{1\leq i_1<\cdots <i_k\leq n} \sum_{t=1}^kx_{i_t}$.
Why does equality hold? I cannot establish even for $k=2$.

What books are you using and what have you learned so far about majorization?  Some of the consequences of e.g. Birkhoff-von Neumann can be interpretted through the  Rearrangement Inequality.  And the Rearrangement Inequality yields a rather simple proof to your question.  I suggest you try applying it and showing your work for $k=2$ and $k=3$.

I saw this remark mentioned in Bhatia's matrix analysis book but before Birkhoff's result. So I assume it just follows from the definition which I do not see how exactly.

The Rearrangement Inequality, a staple of high school math contests, is much simpler than Birkhoff-von Neumann, etc.  Apply it with $x$ and a tuple/vector containing $k$ 1's and $n-k$ 0's -- again I suggest explicitly  doing this for $k=2$ and $k=3$.  (My other point was the Rearrangement Inequality will pay dividends later once a lot of the majorization concepts have had time to sink-in.)

This is the first time I've heard of this. Thanks for pointing it out to me. Will read it first.
